# Incorrect HTML content while using python beautiful soup and requests package

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The HTML content I get after parsing a webpage using JSoup and BeautifulSoup is different as seen below. Does anyone have the same issue and can you please let me know what was done to fix this?

Check the third line in each block -

======= JSoup

```
<div class="col-full">
 <p><strong>Index Notifications</strong></p>
 <p></p><br>
<p> <br /> <b> March 28, 2014</b>
<br >
<br >
```

======= BeautifulSoup

```
<div class="col-full">
<p><strong>Index Notifications</strong></p>
<p><p> <br>
<b> March 28, 2014</b>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: If you have broken HTML input, parsers have to make the best of it. Different parsers do this differently.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try using the lxml parser. How did you know I was doing wisdomtree? :-)

Comment: Pure luck; a Google search on the specific two phrases in the snippet (using quotes) returned only one hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When parsing broken HTML, different parsers will try to repair the broken tags differently; there are no hard and fast rules on how to handle such errors.

BeautifulSoup can [make use of different parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), and each will handle your content differently:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'http://www.wisdomtree.com/etfs/index-notices.aspx'
>>> html = requests.get(url).content
>>> BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='col-full')
<div class="col-full">
<p><strong>Index Notifications</strong></p>
<p><p> <br>
<b> March 28, 2014</b>
<br> <br>
# ... cut ...
>>> BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find('div', class_='col-full')
<div class="col-full">
<p><strong>Index Notifications</strong></p>
<p></p><p> <br/>
<b> March 28, 2014</b>
<br/> <br/>
# ... cut ...
>>> BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib').find('div', class_='col-full')
<div class="col-full">

            <p><strong>Index Notifications</strong></p>
            <p></p><p> <br/>
<b> March 28, 2014</b>
<br/>  <br/>
# ... cut ...
```

The `html5lib` parser is the slowest, but will generally parse broken HTML exactly like most browsers would. Both `lxml` and `html5lib` parsed this specific section of the document pretty much like JSoup did.